# Is there a way to change root of an already registered service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

For example my service worker registered under some.api.com/js/sw.js.
I want to re-register it under some.api.com/sw.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply re-register with a different scope. What did you try and in what way didn't it work? (I'm also assuming you mean "scope" instead of "root".)